# iOS - UITextField subclass with datasource: When/where do you call the datasource methods?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I am subclassing UITextField to to display some data. I want to use the same datasource - delegate pattern like UITableView.

```
@interface MySubClass : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<MyDataSource> myDatasource;
    @property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<MyDelegate> myDelegate;

    -(void) loadStuff;
@end

@implementation MySubClass
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    ...
    self.delegate = self; // For the UITextField
    ...
}

-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [self doStuff];
}

-(void) loadStuff {
    Data * data = [self.myDatasource ...];
    NSString * string = // do stuff to the data for display
    self.text = string; //Calls layoutSubviews again, infinite loop.
}
@end
```

I thought about using layoutSubviews to fetch data from the datasource, and display it.The problem with that is, setting the text to the data I just processed, triggers a call to layoutSubviews again. So you have an infinite loop.

In fact changing the view in anyway seems to trigger a call to layoutSubviews.

Is it possible to duplicate what UITableView does with its datasource?

Comment: You can cache the data from your data source to avoid querying it when you have the latest data cached already. Make a `needRefresh` flag, set it to `NO` after you read from the data source delegate, and let the user set it to `YES` when `reloadData` is invoked.